# How long should I leave my wheat beer in bottles before opening

Tags: beer, bottle-conditioning, wheat-beer

So far the beer has been in primary fermentation for 11 days, and in bottles now for 4 days.
When would you expect the beer would hit optimum flavor and when will it be drinkable/pleasant?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the temperature at which you're storing it, it should be fully carbonated in 0 to 10 days.   The best way to determine this is to open one up and try it and see if it's carbonated yet.  If it's not yet, then give it a couple more days.  Most wheat beers are not really meant for aging, so it should be pleasant/drinkable as soon as it is carbonated.

In my experience, most homebrew hits optimum flavor when you have 1-3 bottles remaining out of the batch.

Comment: "In my experience, most homebrew hits optimum flavor when you have 1-3 bottles remaining out of the batch." This is too funny, I have the same experience.... My last 3 beers are always the best...